# php echo border colour

Tags: php, mysql, html, echo

This seems reletively simple compared to what I have done so far but it doesn't appear to work!

I want to define the `border-bottom` as a colour that is specified in the database. Lets say for example I want the border colour to be ***RED***.

My row in the db is ***border_colour*** and my recordset is recorded as `$row_club`.

My page layout is as follows:

```
<?php 
    require_once('../Connections/cl25theuclone.php');

$club_id = $_GET['club_id'];


mysql_select_db($database, $db_table);
$query_club = "SELECT * FROM clubs WHERE club_id=$club_id";
$club = mysql_query($query_club, $cl25theuclone) or die(mysql_error());
$row_club = mysql_fetch_assoc($club);
$totalRows_club = mysql_num_rows($club);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #header{
               border-bottom: 15px solid; /* This bit works as per normal */
               border-bottom-color: <?php echo $row_club['border_colour']?>; 
            }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
          <div id="header">

          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is happening is its displaying the border-bottom as *15px* and *solid* but it's just coming out the default black and not the specified value in the mySQL db.

I have so far pulled out all other info from the db using this method without any issues, aswell as creating the dynamic URL.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I want to keep it as simple as possible really

Comment: So, what are you getting if you do `var_dump($row_club['border_colour']);` ? Also, please include your select / execute of the query involving `$row_club`

Comment: In cases like this, you don't need to check your db-data, you only need to check the actual produced html. The browser doesn't care where the html is coming from or how it was produced. So, it coming from some dynamic db query is irrelevant. Just check your html source to see what your browser is dealing with.

Comment: @Yoshi  I want it to be editable by the admin through their login portal, hence the need for it to pick it up from the database.

Comment: Put a terminator after ['border_colour']; not sure if this your actual code or a demonstration but php errors will break html etc.

Comment: @Epodax the response I got was ' string(0) "" '. I have now updated to show my select in the main question

Comment: @SamAnderson What I tried to explain is that you're debugging this the wrong way. The first step should be to check the final html source. If that is invalid and as such the cause for the wrongly colored bored, only then should you check why the value is invalid. But, and that is the main point, seeing in what way the value is invalid would give you a clue on how to debug further. When debugging, walk *backwards* without *jumping*.

Comment: You're not doing ANY error checking at all, start making sure that your query executes and that it returns with the data that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
        #header{
           border-bottom: 15px solid <?php echo $row_club['border_colour']; ?>; 
        }
</style>
```

Or even better:

```
<?php $color = $row_club['border_colour']; ?>

<style type="text/css">
            #header{
               border-bottom: 15px solid <?php echo !empty($color) ? $color : 'red'; ?>; 
            }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be an idiot and put the 'red' in the wrong row.... Oops!